# arm-uclinuxeabi-gcc: Command not found

Tags: linux, stm32, arm

День добрый.
Пытаюсь скомпилировать проект [linux-stm32f7](https://github.com/angmouzakitis/linux-stm32f7)

ОС под которой я собираю это Ubuntu 14.04

Пытаюсь выполнить всё как указано в README

1. make stm32f746_disco_defconfig
2. sudo tar xf initdir.tar

Скачал  [arm-2011.03-46-arm-uclinuxeabi-i686-pc-linux-gnu.tar.bz2](https://sourcery.mentor.com/public/gnu_toolchain/arm-uclinuxeabi/arm-2011.03-46-arm-uclinuxeabi-i686-pc-linux-gnu.tar.bz2)

Добавил через /etc/environment путь до библиотеки PATH="/home/astroenginner/arm-2011.03/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/..."

3. export ARCH=arm
4. export CROSS_COMPILE=arm-uclinuxeabi-
5. make

Тут мне выдаёт ошибку

```
make: arm-uclinuxeabi-gcc: Command not found
include/linux/version.h
include/generated/utsrelease.h
`include/generated/mach-types.h' is up to date.
/bounds.s
/bin/sh: 1: arm-uclinuxeabi-gcc: not found
make[1]: *** [kernel/bounds.s] Error 127
make: *** [prepare0] Error 2
```

Хотя терминал говорит что такая команда существует.

```
astroenginner@Miracle:~/linux-stm32f7$ arm-uclinuxeabi-
arm-uclinuxeabi-addr2line  arm-uclinuxeabi-gdbtui
arm-uclinuxeabi-ar         arm-uclinuxeabi-gprof
arm-uclinuxeabi-as         arm-uclinuxeabi-ld
arm-uclinuxeabi-c++        arm-uclinuxeabi-ld.real
arm-uclinuxeabi-c++filt    arm-uclinuxeabi-nm
arm-uclinuxeabi-cpp        arm-uclinuxeabi-objcopy
arm-uclinuxeabi-elf2flt    arm-uclinuxeabi-objdump
arm-uclinuxeabi-elfedit    arm-uclinuxeabi-ranlib
arm-uclinuxeabi-flthdr     arm-uclinuxeabi-readelf
arm-uclinuxeabi-g++        arm-uclinuxeabi-size
arm-uclinuxeabi-gcc        arm-uclinuxeabi-sprite
arm-uclinuxeabi-gcc-4.5.2  arm-uclinuxeabi-strings
arm-uclinuxeabi-gcov       arm-uclinuxeabi-strip
arm-uclinuxeabi-gdb        
astroenginner@Miracle:~/linux-stm32f7$ arm-uclinuxeabi-
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, что делать, как быть, куда копать?

Comment: намёк: i386 и amd64 — это несколько разные архитектуры процессоров. и если вы хотите запускать блобы, скомпилированные для i386, вам надо [добавить поддержку этой архитектуры](https://wiki.debian.org/ru/Multiarch/HOWTO). хотя, вероятно, проще будет взять там же, где вы взяли блобы для i386, и архив с блобами для amd64.

Answer (score 1):

Сообщение

```
make: arm-uclinuxeabi-gcc: Command not found
```

говорит о том, что исполняемый модуль *arm-uclinuxeabi-gcc* НЕ найден ни в одном из каталогов, перечисленных в переменной *$PATH* Попробуйте выполнить команду:

```
whereis arm-uclinuxeabi-gcc
```

Если она ничего не выдаст, тогда так и есть. Вы уверены, что исполняемый модуль  *arm-uclinuxeabi-gcc* действительно имеется у Вас на диске? Тогда определите каталог, в котором он расположен. Если не знаете этот каталог, выполните команду:

```
locate arm-uclinuxeabi-gcc
```

Она покажет каталог, в котором расположена программа.

Теперь этот каталог необходимо добавит  в переменную $PATH. Проще всего это сделать, добавив в коенц файла *.bashrc* или *.profile* строчку вида:

```
export PATH="ДобавляемыйКаталог:$PATH"
```

После этого выйдите из системы и повторно войдите. Модуль *arm-uclinuxeabi-gcc*
станет виден из переменной $PATH.